# How to print only some specific numbers in with JSON ,SWIFT?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

1.I have this array and i want to extract only the "rate" values.
I want y Array to look like this
array = [6,355.1675 , 4,826.3112 , 5,429.8488]

```
[{
code = USD;
description = "United States Dollar";
rate = "6,355.1675";
"rate_float" = "6355.1675";
symbol = "&#36;";
}, {
code = GBP;
description = "British Pound Sterling";
rate = "4,826.3112";
"rate_float" = "4826.3112";
symbol = "&pound;";
}, {
code = EUR;
description = Euro;
rate = "5,429.8488";
"rate_float" = "5429.8488";
symbol = "&euro;";
}]
```

Comment: This question is way too broad and shows no research whatsoever. Please post your current attempt and narrow down what exact problem you have with it - this site is *not* a homework solver.

Comment: You should convert the objects to structs (or classes) and than you can filter your array based on the object's properties

Comment: A simple `map()` should do the tric. If you are new to coding in general, I'd recommend rather to do a for loop, because that's basic knowledge that should be mastered.

Comment: is this json decoded ? or plain String ? or data ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have JSON that contains an array of dictionaries.

Write some code that:

Decodes the JSON into native objects. At the simplest it would be converted to an array of dictionaries.

You could then write code that loops through the array, extracts the `rate` value for each array entry, and prints it.

As others have said, you could do this with a map statement, but if you're new to programming then the for loop approach is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you array is called `array`, then you can do it this way:

```
array.map { print ($0["rate"] }
```

Comment: or `array.compactMap { $0["rate"] }.forEach { print($0) }` to avoid printing optionals